# Collision detection with entities/AI

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection, rpg, npc

I'm making my first game in Java, a top down 2D RPG.
I've handled basic collision detection, rendering and have added an NPC, but I'm stuck on how to handle interaction between the player and the NPC.

Currently I'm drawing out my level and then drawing characters, NPCs and animated tiles on top of this. The problem is keeping track of the NPCs so that my Character class can interact with methods in the NPC classes on collision.

I'm not sure my method of drawing the level and drawing everything else on top is a good one - can anyone shed any light on this topic?

Comment: That's typically how drawing is done - in layers.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm new to game development and although it might seem obvious to an experienced game dev some things just puzzle me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't be afraid to just keep track of the enemies in an ArrayList or something and loop through the enemies to check explicitly if they collide.

```
for(Enemy enemy : enemiesArray) {
    if(player.collidesWith(enemy))
        //Do something
}
```

Unless you have a **lot** of enemies or you're crammed for performance, I don't see anything wrong with this approach.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up for me. I think I'll only have 3 or 4 NPCs or enemies at a time anyways.